# Understanding Stochastic Processes

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables, definition, martingales

I think I have an understanding of how a stochastic process is defined technically, but I've recently come across an example of one given in my notes that doesn't seem to fit with how I understood them. I would like to ask whether my understanding of stochastic processes is incorrect, or if the example given doesn't fit the definition.

Definition: A stochastic process in discrete time is a sequence of random variables $X_{1},X_{2},...$ all on the $same$ probability space $(\Omega,F,P)$.

The example here will show you what my understanding of this definition is:
For a simple random walk each outcome is a sequence of "H" or "T" so we can write $\omega=\omega_{1}\omega_{2},...$ where $\omega_{i}\in{H,T}$. Then $(Z_{n})_{n\geq0}$ is defined by $Z_{i}(\omega)=Z_{i}(\omega_{1}\omega_{2},...\omega_{i},...)$$=$ \begin{cases} 
      1 & \omega_{i}=H \\
      0 & \omega_{i}=T 
       &   
   \end{cases}
Then $(X_{n})_{n\geq0}$ where $X_{n}=X_{0} +\sum_{i=1}^{n} Z_{i}$ is the simple random walk starting at $X_{0}$.

My understanding breaks down when the $Z_{i}$ are described to be independent and identically distributed. I think I can see how these random variables could be independent, however, to be identically distributed would mean if $Z_{1}(\omega)=1$ then $Z_{i}(\omega)=1$ $\forall i\geq0$. To me this doesn't make sense. What am I missing here?

Comment: Identically distributed means the probability of being 1 or 0 is the same for all of them. It's not a set structure concept, it needs the probability measure there to make sense.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was missing. The other answers make sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that $Z_1$ and $Z_i$ are identically distributed does not tell you that $Z_1=1$ implies $Z_i=1$. It only tells you  that $P(Z_1=1)=P(Z_i=1)$.

Comment: So where does my understanding go wrong? If we take any outcome from my example $\omega=\omega_{1}\omega_{2},...$ and apply $Z_{1}(\omega)$, this has been defined so it considers only the first term in sequence of $\omega_{1},\omega_{2},...$ and gives us $1$ or $0$ depending on whether it is a "H" or "T". If we apply $Z_{2}(\omega)$ to the same outcome this must also only consider the first term in this sequence, since $Z_{2}$ is an identical map to $Z_{1}$ and we are evaluating both at the same outcome.

Comment: This is assuming I am correct in thinking $Z_{1}:\Omega\rightarrow R$ and $Z_{i}:\Omega\rightarrow R$ being identically distributed just means the functions are the same ($Z_{1}(\omega)=Z_{i}(\omega),  \forall\omega\in\Omega$)?

Answer (score 0):

$Z_1(\omega)=1$ implies $Z_i(\omega)=1$ for all $i$ is definitely false.

What is true is that $\mathbb{P}(Z_1=1)=\mathbb{P}(Z_i=1)$ for all $i$.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is false given my definition of the outcomes in the sample space. If $Z_{1}$ only considers the first term of a sequence $\omega=\omega_{1}\omega_{2},...$ of "H" and "T", then if $Z_{2}$ is identical it must also only consider the first term in this sequence. I understand that this is not how a random walk works in reality however I can't reconcile the definition of a stochastic process with this. Where have I made a mistake in my example that means I am not describing a simple random walk?

Comment: You have a big misunderstanding about identical distribution. Two RV's are identically distributed if their laws coincide. I.e. $X\stackrel{d}{=} Y \iff \mathbb{P}_X = \mathbb{P}_Y$. This definitely does not imply that $X=Y$. For example, consider a random variable $X$ and change $X$ on a set of probability $0$. Then $X$ and the 'modified X' are not equal yet there distributions must coincide.